# Where should I add ActionDispatch middleware for a Rails API which includes both Web views and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, react-rails

I have an application which uses a React component to update the user profile. With a backend of Rails, I'm attempting to pass a flash message on the `#update` action which is connected to the Rails API that I built for the React frontend. `ActionController::API` doesn't have the middleware of `ActionController::Base` and I can't figure out where to include the `ActionDispatch` middleware for the `ActionController::API`.

I've tried adding it as a module (hoping that it may already be within the application):

**Controller**

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
    include ActionDispatch::Flash
```

I've also tried including the middleware into the `config/application.rb`

**config/application.rb**

```
module Subs
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
          generate.assets false
          generate.helper false
          generate.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
        end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
  end
end
```

I imagine that adding it to a general `config/application.rb` is redundant as the `ActionDispatch::Flash` is already included in the application.

Where could I add a middleware specifically for the `ActionController::API` ? Or how could I give it access to the `ActionDispatch::Flash` that is already present in the `ActionController::Base`?